# SASS mixin to include code block depending on whether body has class (or grand parent)

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I'm trying to create a **mixin** that allows me to write code blocks flexibly depending on whether body has a certain class.

```
@mixin when($class) {

    body.#{$class} & {

        @content;

    }
}
```

**Use Cases**

```
#hero {

    @include when('theme--dark') {

        span { 

            content: 'Good Evening'; 

        }
    }
}
```

```
#hero {

    @include when('page-landing') {

        button.cta { 

            padding: 3rem 5rem;

            font-size: 3rem;

            background-color: $green;
        }
    }
}
```

even better if the following can be achieved

```
@mixin when($parent, $class) {

    #{$parent}.#{$class} & {

        @content;

    }

}
```

```
#hero {

    @include when('body','page-landing') {

        button.cta { 

            padding: 3rem 5rem;

            font-size: 3rem;

            background-color: $green;

        }
    }
}
```

non of the previous codes work, not even certain of the syntax but wondering if something similar can be produced, any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: the code actually works, i had minor syntax issues but i'll leave the question open in case anyone has better implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your approach is absolutely fine, here is a slightly cleaner implementation, that grants a little more flexibilty when it comes to the number of selectors you want to check for.

```
@mixin when($selectors...) {
  $n: "";
  
  @each $selector in $selectors {
    $n: str-insert($n, "#{$selector}", str-length($n) + 1);
  }
  
  #{$n} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

```
#hero {
  @include when('body', '[dark-mode=true]', '.primary') {
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Comment: First i'm glad i didn't close the question, second your version is much better, i love the flexibility and reusability in your implementation, thanks for this!!